# ContextMenu disappears immediately after appearing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, contextmenu

I have a context menu but it is disappearing instantly after it shows up.

```xml
<TextBlock Name="InputtedAddress" Text="{Binding Path=InputtedAddress}"  MouseDown="InputtedAddress_MouseDown"/>
```

```cs
System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenu thisMenu; 
   private void InputtedAddress_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.RightButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                thisMenu = new System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenu();
                MenuItem thisMenuItem = new MenuItem() { Header = "Zoom to Incident" };
                thisMenuItem.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(thisMenuItem_Click);
                thisMenu.Items.Add(thisMenuItem);
                thisMenu.IsOpen = true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why are you creating and populating the context menu like that? Why not just assign it in XAML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should assign your menu to the [ContextMenu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.contextmenu.aspx%5C) property of your `TextBlock` so that the opening and positioning will be taken care of for you.  You also don't need to create the menu in each MouseDown; just create it once and assign it to the `ContextMenu` property.

In XAML:

```xml
<TextBlock 
    Name="InputtedAddress" 
    Text="{Binding Path=InputtedAddress}"  
    >
    <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu> 
             <MenuItem
                 Header="Zoom to Incident"
                 Click="ContextMenu_Click"
             />
         </ContextMenu>
    </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
</TextBlock>
```

If you do want to show it manually you will need to position it before showing it by setting the [PlacementTarget](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contextmenu.placementtarget.aspx) property, something like this:

```
private void InputtedAddress_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RightButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        thisMenuPlacementTarget = InputtedAddress;
        thisMenu.IsOpen = true;
    }
}
```

P.S. "Inputted" is not a word :)

Answer (score 2):

It's likely because you're not marking the `MouseDown` event to handled. Set `e.Handled` to `true` and it will no longer propagate and your `ContextMenu` will stay open.

That said, this is an awful way to assign a `ContextMenu` in the first place. Why not just do this:

```
<TextBlock ...>
    <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Zoom to Incident" Click="thisMenuItem_Click"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Based on the XAML the OP is handling MouseDown.  The (immediate) problem is that the context menu is not assigned to any control and its position is never set.  That said, it should just be assigned in XAML here.

Comment: @Ed: he's not marked the routed event as handled, so it will continue bubbling up the visual tree. Another control will handle it, and I'm assuming that this results in the `ContextMenu` being closed.